# JSON is not rendering on popup window JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a parent window from where a Chile window is opening and then execute a JSON with parameter from parent window, collect data from database and display in table on child window. below is the code in GetJson is not working as expected and returns nothing. Any help is appreciated

Child.SCHTML:

```
<div id="chartdivd" >
<table id="bugsDetail" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Segoe UI'">
                        <tr class="tableRow">
                            <th class="tableHeader">BugId</th>
                            <th class="tableHeader">BugType </th>
                            <th class="tableHeader">ResolutionTime </th>
                            <th class="tableHeader">BugTitle</th>

                           </tr>
 </table>

</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="amCharts/images/style.css" type="text/css">
<div id="SQLLoading" style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Segoe UI'"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.selectboxes.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >


    $(document).ready(function () {

    var paras = window.opener.parabug;
    alert(paras);
    var Pars1 = "NoData";
    $.getJSON('/common/JSONRequest', {query: "BugsDetail", pars: paras, db: "Deployment_Metrics"}, function (data) {

        if (data.length > 0)
         {
             for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            {
                $('#bugsDetail').append('<tr class="tableRow"><td class="tableCell"> ' + data[i]['BugID'] + '</td><td class="tableCell">' + data[i]['BugType'] + '</td><td class="tableCell">' + data[i]['ResolutionTime'] + '</td><td class="tableCell">' + data[i]['BugTitle'] + '</td></tr>');
              }

        }
       else 
       {
              $('#bugsDetail').append('<tr class="tableRow"><td class="tableCell"> No data</td><td class="tableCell">No data</td><td class="tableCell">No data</td><td class="tableCell">No data</td></tr>');
        }
    });
    });



    </script>
```

Comment: Check that server response is valid JSON.

Comment: and How do I do that please? I am using webmatrix so tough to denug also the same JSON is working on other window.

Comment: At least output it with `alert()` and make sure visually that this is JSON at all, and not e.g. some server-error message.